# apache redirect document root: don't know where to put the RewriteRule

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am trying to redirect the document root to a specific folder (eg mysite.com to mysite.com/myfolder). However, when i tried, it still shows the default apache home page.

I followed the example [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html) where I put

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /myfolder/ [R]
```

in several sections like the Directory, Directory "c:/wamp/www/"   and VirtualHost *:80 but it doesn't work. I have switched on the rewrite_module. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below RewriteEngine on, write

```
RewriteLog "logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

and restart the apache server. Now check rewrite.log file.

This will help you debugging.

for solution try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /myfolder [R,L]
```

write this in you virtual host entry.

Comment: ok i managed to solve it by putting it in the VirtualHost. one thing i overlooked was not uncommenting the httpd.conf file (around line 470)
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf. hope it helps any newbie out there trying to work this out...

Comment: @icube: Please accept the answer in that case.